# In Java super.getClass() prints an unexpected name in the derived class - why is that?

Tags: java, super

Could you help me understand what gets printed in the code below  `System.out.println(super.getClass().getName());`?

I see `"PrintSubClass3"` printed, even when I have mentioned `super`.

```
class PrintClass {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    void printMe() {
        System.out.println("X is " + x + ", Y is " + y);
        System.out.println("I am an instance of the class " +super.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class PrintSubClass3 extends PrintClass {
    int z = 3;
    void printMe() {
        System.out.println("x is " + x + ", y is " + y + ", z is " + z);
        System.out.println(super.getClass().getName());
        super.printMe();
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        PrintSubClass3 obj = new PrintSubClass3();
        obj.printMe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`super.getClass()` calls the method `getClass()` as defined by the parent class (ignoring any `getClass` method you may have defined in the class itself -- not sure if that is even possible with `getClass`, probably `final`).

This ends up calling `Object#getClass`, which returns the runtime class of the instance (which is what it is, an instance of `PrintSubClass3`).

All `super` does is let you call into the implementation of methods that you could otherwise not reach because you have overridden them. Here, it is redundant, as `this.getClass()` and `super.getClass()` end up at the same method.

Answer (score 0):

`getClass()` method returns the runtime class of this Object. In another words, your obj object, which is the object of class name `PrintSubClass3` . So because of that, it will return  `PrintSubClass3`.

so calling inside your class, it will give you its own class, even though there is `super` keyword. there is super keyword, it will go to its superClass for finding the method getClass(), but since its not implemented explicitly in superClass, getClass() method will work as documentation says ~ it will return runtime class of the object.

If you really want to print your superClass's name you should do this

```
 System.out.println(super.getClass().getSuperclass());
```

I hope this will clear your confusion.

> what is the ideal way to print name of the class?

simply type this  (you can print without super keyword )

```
     System.out.println(getClass().getName());   //Prints your local class
      System.out.println(getClass().getSuperclass()); //Prints your superClass
```

Comment: `super.getClass().getSuperclass() `  Why not just `getClass().getSuperclass()` ? What is the `super` doing there?

Comment: as i wrote there, even though there is keyword super, it won't give you className of superClass, because documentation clearly states that `getClass()` method returns the runtime class of this object. In another words, the object's class. that's y it returns the name. You can print class name without calling super.

Comment: Also, to add, there is `super` keyword, it will go to its `superClass` for finding the method `getClass()`, but since its not implemented explicitly in superClass, `getClass()` method will work as documentation says ~ it will return runtime class of the object. I hope this will make things clear